# Read, Add, Delete Windows users in .NET

Tags: .net, windows, addition

I want to Read, Add and Delete users from a Windows using .NET code. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'from a Windows'?

Comment: I guess, he means the different user profiles for Windows OS.

Comment: If thats the case, heres a similar question about deleting users http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423833/vb-net-remove-user-from-active-directory

Comment: I mean Windows directory users

Comment: Looking to [Manage the Active Directory from a .NET application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188700.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some sample code for creating a windows user:

```
public static bool CreateLocalWindowsAccount(string username, string password, string displayName, string description, bool canChangePwd, bool pwdExpires)
{
    try
    {
        PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
        UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(context);
        user.SetPassword(password);
        user.DisplayName = displayName;
        user.Name = username;
        user.Description = description;
        user.UserCannotChangePassword = canChangePwd;
        user.PasswordNeverExpires = pwdExpires;
        user.Save();

        //now add user to "Users" group so it displays in Control Panel
        GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "Users");
        group.Members.Add(user);
        group.Save();

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error creating account: {0}", ex.Message);
        return false;
    }

}
```

Adding a reference to System.DirectoryServices will let you read all windows users doing something like this:

```
DirectoryEntry localMachine = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName);
DirectoryEntry admGroup = localMachine.Children.Find("administrators", "group");
object members = admGroup.Invoke("members", null);
foreach (object groupMember in (IEnumerable)members)
{
    DirectoryEntry member = new DirectoryEntry(groupMember);
    lstUsers.Items.Add(member.Name);
}
```

The [DirectoryServices Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx) in general should let you navigate and read the Active Directory

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the ActiveDirectory and DirectoryEntry

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory
Imports System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
```

`LDAP` is one option I would think `WinNT` would works as well.

You can access the directory with WinNT:// like this

```
    Dim de As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry()  
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs Handles Button1.Click      
     de.Path = "WinNT://*****".Replace("*****", ActiveDirectory.DomainGetCurrentDomain.Name)
```

Here are a few helpful links that have examples for adding/removing etc

[Working with Users](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/active_directory_in_vbnet.aspx)

[SO Remove User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423833/vb-net-remove-user-from-active-directory)

Also I had a few questions involving ActiveDirectory use a month or so ago (so I don't remember them in depth). Maybe some stuff from my profile can help you out. Good Luck

Comment: Or, for .NET 3.5 and up - use `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` which is **a lot** easier to use than straight S.DS ....

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other answers which are definitely valid and good we have also used LINQ to AD...

http://linqtoad.codeplex.com/

...on some projects which can make simple querying quite easy.