# Making a windows user using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, windows, account

I'm trying to make an application that will create a windows user. This is to aid me in the work I'm currently doing at my internship. I have been looking on Google for days for someway to do this but only found one script so far http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/371016-create-windows-user-account Though when I try running it I get "undefined error" I also tried making a .bat file that will create a user though there I met problems with the encoding as described here https://superuser.com/questions/675369/what-encoding-to-get-to-work

If anyone have any idea on how to do this I would be grateful if you could share it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read, Add, Delete Windows users in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614378/read-add-delete-windows-users-in-net)

Comment: @JMK Though that is for C and I'm trying to make this in VB

Comment: Actually the second answer is in VB.Net, but I don't think it would be that difficult to convert the C# answer to VB if you tried a little :)

Comment: On exactly what line do you get the `undefined error`? You could also use the [code example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306271) from Microsoft.

Comment: @Rik I get it on "oUser.SetInfo()"